# Layout displaying ImageView at the bottom of the page

Tags: java, android

Im using a collapsing toolbar/scrollview in my activity. but my image (.jpg) always displays at the bottom of the page but i want it under the collapsing toolbar.

i have tried the following:
setting the gravity = top, match_parent, fill_parent, android:layout_below, changing the appbarlayout height  but none have solved the problem stated.

heres a screenshot:
[image]

#### night_rui.xml

```
       <tools:android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="learn.navdrawbase.Rui">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dhotelz">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/evebg">


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>




    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dhotelz"
        android:layout_above="@id/MyAp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:src="@drawable/dhoteldesc"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</tools:android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

#### Rui.java

```
   package learn.navdrawbase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by User on 2/4/2016.
 */
public class Rui extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.night_rui);
    }
}
```

**BaseActivity.java** if needed:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    protected NavigationView mNavigationView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    /**
     * Helper method that can be used by child classes to
     * specify that they don't want a {@link Toolbar}
     * @return true
     */
    protected boolean useToolbar() {
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Helper method to allow child classes to opt-out of having the
     * hamburger menu.
     * @return
     */
    protected boolean useDrawerToggle() {
        return true;
    }




    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);

        getActionBarToolbar();

        setupNavDrawer();
    }//end setContentView


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Global methods as
        /*
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
            mHandler = new Handler();
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
            ...
         */
    }



    protected Toolbar getActionBarToolbar() {
        if (mActionBarToolbar == null) {
            mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            if (mActionBarToolbar != null) {
                // Depending on which version of Android you are on the Toolbar or the ActionBar may be
                // active so the a11y description is set here.
                mActionBarToolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.navdrawer_description_a11y));
                //setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);

                if (useToolbar()) { setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
                } else { mActionBarToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE); }

            }
        }

        return mActionBarToolbar;
    }



    private void setupNavDrawer() {


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (mDrawerLayout == null) {
            return;
        }


        // use the hamburger menu
        if( useDrawerToggle()) {
            mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, mDrawerLayout, mActionBarToolbar,
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mToggle);
            mToggle.syncState();
        }
        else if(useToolbar() && getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            // Use home/back button instead
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(ContextCompat
                    .getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha));
        }


        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }




    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_1:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, MyHome.class));
                break;

            case R.id.nav_2:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, MyTour.class));
                break;

            case R.id.nav_3:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, MyTranslator.class));
                break;

            case R.id.nav_4:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, MySettings.class));
                break;

            case R.id.nav_5:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, MyAbout.class));
                break;


        }

        closeNavDrawer();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_out_left);

        return true;
    }


    protected boolean isNavDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    protected void closeNavDrawer() {
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }



    /**
     * Enables back navigation for activities that are launched from the NavBar. See
     * {@code AndroidManifest.xml} to find out the parent activity names for each activity.
     * @param intent
     */
    private void createBackStack(Intent intent) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            TaskStackBuilder builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            builder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
            builder.startActivities();
        } else {
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }


}//end BaseActivity
```

Comment: do you really think that an appbar has height of 256 dp?

Comment: @VivekMishra the collapsing toolbar yes, i tried to change it to 50dp but the image is still opening at the bottom

Comment: if you do think so then there is no solution to your problem. Only way is to decrease it's height to 56 dp

Comment: i edited the dp and it did not work, i updated my new .xml and a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your **AppBarLayout** height.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but the problem still persists, still displaying at the bottom of the screen and i have to scroll up to view the image

Answer (score 0):

Add theme in your AppBarLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

So you need to use theme:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
```

It's the code and works for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="eb.collapsetoolbarlayout.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bgheader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@drawable/wallpaper2"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Ekta Bhawsar but the image is still at the bottom of the display

Comment: It's because of you are using ImgaeView outside the CollapsingToolbarLayout. please write the code of ImageView inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout. I'll edit my answer and write the correct code.